# Each loop failing in Groovy DSL Pipeline for Jenkins Jobs Builder

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to create dynamic Jenkins job pipeline stages based on an array of values but I can't seem to get the loop functioning as expected, it complains about the syntax I'm using but I can't figure it out, is this a Groovy issue?

**Approach**

```
uat_nodes:
    - 'node1'
    - 'node2'
```

```
dsl: |
    stage('Update UAT dist') {{
        build job: '{key}-{module}-DP-BuildNamedDist-UAT'
    }}
    def UAT_NODES = {uat_nodes}
    UAT_NODES.each { UAT_NODE ->
        stage('Deploy code to UAT node: ' . ${{UAT_NODE}}) {{
            build job: '{key}-{module}-DP-UAT-Nodes', parameters: [
                string(name: 'LIMIT', value: '${{UAT_NODE}}'),
                string(name: 'PLAYBOOK', value: '{playbook}')
            ]
        }}
    }
```

**Error**

```
WorkflowScript: 8: Ambiguous expression could be either a parameterless closure expression or an isolated open code block;
   solution: Add an explicit closure parameter list, e.g. {it -> ...}, or force it to be treated as an open block by giving it a label, e.g. L:{...} @ line 8, column 56.
   e to UAT node: ' . ${{UAT_NODE}}) {{
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, there is a problem with this piece of code: `. ${{UAT_NODE}}`

If strings would have a `$` method, that would call it with a closure inside a closure, that returns UAT_NODE.

I can only assume, that you want to concat strings here similar to perl or php.  This is not how it works in groovy.

Use: `"Deploy code to UAT node: ${UAT_NODE}"`.  **Note the double quotes `"`!  Single quotes `'` won't give you replacement** (this is every other string you are using in your code).